# Do certificate need to be installed to make web request even when we are adding it to ClientCertificates?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, webclient, x509certificate, client-certificates

I'm trying to make a web request using WebClient. I'm adding the client certificate in the web request in the following way:

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
            request.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(AzureKeyVaultHelper.GetCertificate()));
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
            request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 10000;
            return request;
        }
```

And I'm setting following configurations before making the web request:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls 
                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

So here, I'm getting the certificate from Azure Key Vault (but the source doesn't matter). The request works as long as I have the cert installed on my local machine as well. But, when it is not, it says "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel". 
So, I don't understand the whole point of it. When I'm adding the client cert in the request, do I need to have it installed as well?

Please help!!